# Colorbox's overlay not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, colorbox

I just started using Colorbox modal plugin and cannot figure out how to get the overlay.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#button_writereview").colorbox();
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="button_writereview" href="...">Link</a>
```

I notice in the examples that they used a css file and a empty div called `cboxOverlay` in the html file. How does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need to use one of the css files in [the examples](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html) or write your own. This is what controls the appearance of colorbox's windows/overlays/buttons etc.

The `cboxOverlay` element and all other necessary elements are created dynamically when you open one of the windows - you don't have to add it, or any other markup manually. When you saw it, you were probably looking at the *generated* source after opening one (Firebug?) - it shouldn't be there otherwise.